# Reduction from clique to bag automata

Tags: complexity-theory, automata, reductions, parameterized-complexity

I am trying to figure out a reduction to prove $W[1]$-hardness for this, but I am having significant trouble. Here is the problem:

**Bag Automaton**: 
A non deterministic finite state automaton $M=(Q,I,s,F,d)$. $Q$ is the set of states, $I$ is the set of items, $s\in Q$ is the start state, $F\subseteq Q$ is the set of accepting states, $d\subseteq Q\times 2^I\times Q\times 2^I$ is the set of transitions, where $2^I$ is the set of all subsets of $I$. 
A computation of a Bag Automaton starts in $s$, with given item set $I' \subseteq I$. At each step the bag automaton in state $q$ and associated item set  $I^* \subseteq I$ does a state transition $(q,A,q',B)$, $A\subseteq I^*$, which sets the state to $q'$ and the bag automaton's item set to $(I'-A) \cup B $. $M$ accepts if there is a sequence of transitions from $s$ to an $f \in F$.

**Bag Automaton Computation**
Input: A Bag Automaton $M=(Q,I,s,F,d)$, a set $I' \subseteq I$ and a positive integer $k$.

Parameters: $k$

Question: Can $M$ accept on $I'$ by executing at most $k$ transitions?

I am almost certain a reduction from clique where the initial bag contains all vertices will work, but I cannot figure out how to formalize it.

Comment: I edited the question to make the details of the definition more clear. Please check that I didn't introduce any errors.

Comment: How far did you get? Where did you get stuck with the reduction?